# kubernetes: service name resolution with namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

Created a `kubernetes` cluster with private topology on `aws` using `kops`

My application exposes several services. As expected, services communicate among each other using their names, i.e. the `name` field below:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: staging_namespace
```

Here is the question:

Assuming that I will deploy **2** version of my application (e.g. `testing` and `staging`) in **different namespaces**, will this prevent service name collision?

Will namespace separation allow

- `service1` reach the correct `myservice` in `staging_namespace` in my `staging` deployment
- `service1` reach the correct `myservice` in `testing_namespace` in my `testing` deployment

?

Using

```
kops version
Version 1.8.0 (git-5099bc5)
```

and

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.1", GitCommit:"f38e43b221d08850172a9a4ea785a86a3ffa3b3a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-11T23:27:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.4", GitCommit:"9befc2b8928a9426501d3bf62f72849d5cbcd5a3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-20T05:17:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, Namespace is a virtual cluster in k8s cluster, therefore it provides isolation and separation of concern. It does not conflict If you have same services or pods in different namespaces.

All service are assigned a DNS Record which is unique therefore there is no conflict. for instance,

```
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local.
```

**In your case, it would be like this**

```
my-svc.staging_namespace.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.testing_namespace.svc.cluster.local.
```

I have attached a link for further research. 
[services-networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

**Edit:1**

**Purpose and Motivation of Namespaces**

The functionality of namespace is to provide the logical separation of environments which is providing a uniqueness to k8s resources even being a same pod or service.

> Kubernetes supports multiple virtual clusters backed by the same physical cluster. These virtual clusters are called namespaces.

[Virtual cluster are called namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Comment: it is by no means a "virtual cluster", just a way to organise stuff inside, that can, but does not have to  be used for different ways of isolation like ie. NetworkPolicies

Comment: As I Understand, The functionality of namespace is to provide the **logical separation** of environments which is providing a uniqueness to k8s resources even being a same pod or service.  network policies have different purpose and motivation in the cluster.

Comment: >>Kubernetes supports multiple virtual clusters backed by the same physical cluster. These virtual clusters are called namespaces.[virtual cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

Comment: HI @Radek,  As I understand from k8s official website, It's explained by the same terminology. I guess You are misunderstanding with two separate things. In my answer, I tried to explain with reasonable contents.

Comment: @Radek, If you do not mind to tell me, why the answer is not comprehensive and it deserved to be downvoted?    It might help me to evaluate me to write more comprehensive answers in future. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes, you can put resources with the same name into separate namespaces and there will be no collision.